# Import Java BigInteger

Tags: java, import, biginteger

I have to do some project with the Java class BigInteger. (Representation of Rational Numbers)

The first problem occurs when I try to import it.

I can use `import java.math.*;`

But as soon as I use `import java.math.BigInteger;`
the BigInteger gets marked red, and does not work anymore.

When importing it by `math.*` I cannot use any of the functions of `BigInteger`, like `.valueOf` or any other.

Had somebody already had this problem and found a solution?

My code so far:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Rational {

    private BigInteger num; //Zähler, Nummerator
    private BigInteger denom; //Nenner, denominator

    public Rational (BigInteger num, BigInteger denom) {
        this.num = num;
        this.denom = denom;
    }
}
```

Comment: "The BigInteger gets marked red"—Sounds like you're using some kind of IDE that you have not mentioned in your question.

Comment: If you are using an IDE try closing it and restarting it, might fix it.

Comment: What kind of IDE you using right now? And is the JDK configured correctly? It sounds more like a problem from the IDE due to it works fine if I just copy-paste that class. You could also just try to compile the class by hand and see if you get any compile errors :D

Comment: What exactly is the error message when it gets marked red? Hover your mouse over the mark and/or try to open the "Problem" view while that class is open to see the exact error message. Then edit that into your question.

Answer (score 3):

## Restart IDE

Thanks to Nexevis.

It was as easy as that, stupid not to try this on my own.

Restarted IntelliJ and now it works fine.

Thanks to all the othery, trying to solve my problem.